# Is it possible to perform a XSS attack using jQuery's .attr(attributeName, value) method in the following context?

Tags: jquery, xss

Given is the following html fragment, which is statically typed in an html file:

```
<div id="div001" title="abc">Test</div>
```

Is it possible to perform a XSS attack when the attacker can provide an arbitrary value for the variable `unsafe_string` in the following context:

```
$('#div001').attr("title", unsafe_string);
```

My question is: Is it possible to break out of the attribute value so that some malicious code can get injected and executed? The attacker has only control of `unsafe_string` and nothing else.

I could for example observe that

```
$('#div001').attr("title", '"');
```

results in

```
$('#div001').attr("title") = "\""
```

Comment: If the `attributeName` is a constant `title` then no.

Comment: @Lucero Yes, the assumption is that the attacker can only provide `unsafe_string` and not the `attributeName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as jQuery takes care of escaping the content of `unsafe_string`, so that it is not possible to break out of the attribute value. Writing html or javascript code into the attribute value via jQuery's attr() function will escape the string and will not get interpreted as html or executed as javascript code.

The escaping behaviour can be checked by looking at `$('#div001')[0].outerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a number of vulnerabilities in this code:

1. execution of malicious javascript when you execute `$('#div001').attr("title", unsafe_string);`

Example:
jsp code: `$('#div001').attr("title", ${unsafe_string});`

when unsafe_string value is `"");alert('do nasty stuff')`

generates js code: `$('#div001').attr("title", "");alert('do nasty stuff')`

*edit:* jquery protects you against these 2 by escaping dangerous chars

2. <s>injection of malicious javascript in the attibute value (title)</s>
3. <s>injection of html in the attribute value</s>

You have to escape the unsafe string to protect against all of these (and also you have to validate the unsafe string when you save it in your application). I suggest using an existing security library for this, depending on your technology stack. See more here: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

---

Edit:
  4. If you keep your js code in the html file, you can also be vulnerable to html injection
Example: jsp code:

```
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){$('#mydiv').attr( "title", ${unsafe_string})});
    </script>
    <div id="mydiv" title='abc'>
        something
    </div>
```

When unsafe_string is the string *</script>defaceing my site*
Your page will look like [image: this]

More details about how to test against XSS here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: I cannot agree on point 1., 2. and 3. As far as I could find out, jQuery takes care of escaping the content of `unsafe_string`, so that it is not possible to break out of the attribute value. Writing html or javascript code into the attribute value via jQuery's `attr()` function will escape the string and will not get interpreted as html or executed as javascript code. Escaping `unsafe_string` before setting it with `attr()` will save the attribute value in an unwanted way.

Comment: You are right about 2 & 3. But 1 is still possible, it happens before jquery evaluates the value of unsafe_string

Comment: Ok, now I know what you mean with 1., but this is not my intended use case. The assumption is that the attacker has only control of `unsafe_string` and the given html fragment is statically typed in an html file. Furthermore, in my opinion it is quite uncommon to intentionally produce jQuery or javascript code within jsp, which subsequently, intentionally produces or manipulates html content. Normally, jsp would directly produce the required html content. Nevertheless, this shows an interesting attack vector for a different situation.